# Less voltage more amp? switch characteristis

Tags: switches, current-rating

I have a question regarding switches, relays etc

Ex, if I have a switch rated for 24v 0.5a, can the contacts then safely handle 12v up to 1a? Because the power passing the switch is the same? Or should I anyway use a 12v 1a switch?

Comment: If you come to a bridge which says: max 3 Meters high, max 2 tonnes. You then think: Oh, I am only 1.5 meter high so I can cross with my 4 tonne vehicle?

Comment: Hehe of course not. And good analogy. I thought watts passing through the switch could be used as a limmit. now i know different :)

Comment: @oldfart found a switch that has ratings: 4 AMPS @ 125 V AC or 28 V DC; 2 AMPS @ 250 AC, so while it might not be true about DC, it seems to be true for AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

You must adhere to specs in every aspect. If there's a component that has derating curve, then its datasheet will say so.

Physically, what heats up switches and makes arching weld together contacts is current. Exceeding the current rating is a dangerous game, and you shouldn't play it.

Comment: Ok, thank you :) I sort of understand, I got the idea from series/parallel batteries/transformers, but I understand the concept is entierly different, as the only thing receiving more current there is the load.

Comment: I also thought that watts could be used to see if they generate the same heat. But now I know that is not the only factor. And will find out why. thanks again

Comment: found a switch that has ratings: 4 AMPS @ 125 V AC or 28 V DC; 2 AMPS @ 250 AC, so while it might not be true about DC, it seems to be true for AC.

Answer (score 2):

> ...Because the power passing the switch is the same?

You are misunderstanding what the rating means.  If you see "24V 0.5A" on a switch, it does *not* mean that the switch will drop 24V when 0.5A pass through it.

There *is* a component that will do that:  It's called a 48 Ohm resistor, and it will dissipate 12 Watts of power under those circumstances.

An ideal switch will dissipate *no* power.  The rating "24V 0.5A" actually is two ratings:  "24V" means,  when the switch is *open*, it can safely withstand 24V, and *no* current will flow, and it will dissipate no power.

"0.5A" means, when the switch is closed, it can safely carry 0.5A.  Ideally, the voltage across the switch will be 0V in that case, and the switch will dissipate no power.  In reality, there will be a very small voltage across the switch, and it will dissipate a small amount of power.  "0.5A" means that as long as the current is less than 1/2 an amp, the power dissipated will not be enough to harm the switch or anything else.

The two ratings combined have one other meaning.  When you open the switch contacts, there usually will be a spark.  The spark is hot, and it potentially can damage the switch.  I know a lot less about how arcs form and how they are extinguished, but the combined "24V 0.5A" rating means that the arc will not last long enough to do any harm if the current was 1/2 an amp or less when you started to open the switch, AND the voltage can rise to no more than 24V by the time the current finally stops and the arc goes out.

Comment: I said passing, so that means I understood. I have created a lot of projects, and always according to rating. but was curious on this. But glad you pointed out when exactly the switch is experiencing the load.

Comment: the thing I misunderstood was that voltage and amp must be taken as two independent factors/sources.. I thought you always just considered the end watts/va passing through the contacts/wires etc. Though that was only a thought, and as people has reccomended I have followed specs and datasheets to avoid any danger when I have made projects, also with a good overhead. :)